# Return value based on user input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jQuery (1.7), and not jQueryUI - (how) would it be possible to accomplish the following?

- Call function 1
- Within function 1, a variable is defined and set to the 
  outcome of function 2
- When called, function 2 'on the fly' creates 2 buttons, if
  the first is clicked a value of 'true' is returned, the second returns 'false'
- Within function 1, the variable being set to the outcome of function 2 should wait until there had been user input and a value has been returned
- This value should then be evaluated

Is there any way to do this in jQuery without using an interval/timeout etc to keep looking for an intermediate value being set to the users input?

I've outlined the principle below:

```
function function1(){

    var myVariable=function2;
    // nothing should happen at this point until function2 has returned a response
    if(myVariable){
        alert('true');
    }else{
        alert('false');
    }
}


function function2(){

    var yesbutton=$("<input type='submit' value='yes' />");
    var nobutton=$("<input type='submit' value='no' />");
    $('body').append(yesbutton)
    $('body').append(nobutton)
    nobutton.click(function(){
        return false;
    });
    yesbutton.click(function(){
        return true;
    });

}


function1();
```

As always, many thanks for any help!

Comment: user input is asynchronous unless you're using modal dialogs like `prompt`, `confirm`, or `showModalDialog`. You'll have to use a callback otherwise.

Comment: How would it be possible to implement a callback?

Comment: @ErgoSummary Shankar's solution uses a callback. Well, sortof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible, just maybe not in the way you expected it to be.

```
function function1(){

    var myVariable=function2();
    // nothing should happen at this point until function2 has returned a response
    myVariable.done(function(){
        alert('true');
    }).fail(function(){
        alert('false');
    });
}


function function2(){
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    var yesbutton=$("<input type='submit' value='yes' />");
    var nobutton=$("<input type='submit' value='no' />");
    $('body').append(yesbutton)
    $('body').append(nobutton)
    nobutton.click(deferred.reject);
    yesbutton.click(deferred.resolve);

    return deferred.promise().always(function(){
        yesbutton.add(nobutton).remove();
    });

}


function1();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve it with the help of callbacks. In an ideal world however it would be better to leverage an evented mechanism where you listen for and fire events to update the variable, but that would require quite a lot more effort for this simple example.

```
function function1(){
    function2(function(myVariable){
        if(myVariable){
            alert('true');
        }else{
            alert('false');
        }
    };
}


function function2(callback){

    var yesbutton=$("<input type='submit' value='yes' />");
    var nobutton=$("<input type='submit' value='no' />");
    $('body').append(yesbutton)
    $('body').append(nobutton)
    nobutton.click(function(){
        callback(false);
    });
    yesbutton.click(function(){
        callback(true);
    });
}

function1();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that because function2 has executed and the return value from `click` handlers inside `function2` will not be its return value. But you can achieve it using just one function.

```
function function1(){

    var yesbutton=$("<input type='submit' value='yes' />");
    var nobutton=$("<input type='submit' value='no' />");
    $('body').append(yesbutton)
    $('body').append(nobutton)
    nobutton.click(function(){
        alert('false');
    });
    yesbutton.click(function(){
        alert('true');
    });

}
```

Alternatively you can do this.

```
function function2(yesClickHandler, noClickHandler){
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    var yesbutton=$("<input type='submit' value='yes' />");
    var nobutton=$("<input type='submit' value='no' />");
    $('body').append(yesbutton).append(nobutton);

    nobutton.click(noClickHandler);
    yesbutton.click(yesClickHandler);

    return deferred.promise();

}

function2(function(){
   alert('true');
}, function(){
   alert('false');
});
```

Comment: Indeed, however the reason to have function2 spun out seperately was so it can be repurposed elsewhere- there may be other incidences of functions similar to function1...

Comment: In that case you can pass a callback to function2 and use it.

Comment: Thanks- looks closer, the deferred option Kevin proposed does work- im intrigued by passing the yes/no click handlers?

Comment: I think this solution is better than deffered solution. You can reuse it any number of times simultaneously.

Comment: You can use mine any number of times simultaneously too since it creates a new deferred object each time you use it. The only thing I don't like about mine is that the callbacks are named `done` and `fail` instead of `yes` and `no`, which makes it a little less readable.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in function 1:

```
var myVariable=function2();
```